# MySql insert with duplicate key

Tags: mysql

I have a DB called "csv_db" with a table called "reportinc".

The table has these columns:

`ID incidente`, `Aperto da`, `Stato`, `Categoria`, `Area`, `Sottoarea`, `Titolo`, `Priorità`, `Data/ora apertura`, `Data/Ora risoluzione`, `Data/ora chiusura`, `Inizio Interruzione di servizio`, `Fine interruzione di servizio`, `Conteggio riassegnazioni`, `Gruppo di assegnazione`, `Assegnatario`, `Risolto da`, `Gruppo risoluzione`, `Chiuso da`, `Gruppo di chiusura`, `ID interazione`, `Id Remedy`, `Descrizione`, `Soluzione`, `Servizio Interessato`, `Servizi Interessati`, `CI interessato`, `CI operativo`, `Ultimo aggiornamento da`

The primary and unique key is `ID incidente`

I need to import each day from .CSV (comma separated) and:

1. Insert new rows with new value (`ID incident` also)
2. Update existing rows in the list, if present.

I need to update rows if duplicate, and NOT append.

How to?

Comment: Do we assume your .csv file has values for all columns? Does the file have column headers?

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> If you specify `REPLACE`, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index as an existing row. See [Section 13.2.8, “`REPLACE` Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replace.html).

Therefore:

```sql
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE '/path/to/csv'
    REPLACE
    INTO TABLE csv_db.reportinc
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES
        TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    [IGNORE 1 LINES]
    (`ID incidente`, `Aperto da`, `Stato`, `Categoria`, `Area`, `Sottoarea`,
     `Titolo`, `Priorità`, `Data/ora apertura`, `Data/Ora risoluzione`,
     `Data/ora chiusura`, `Inizio Interruzione di servizio`,
     `Fine interruzione di servizio`, `Conteggio riassegnazioni`,
     `Gruppo di assegnazione`, `Assegnatario`, `Risolto da`,
     `Gruppo risoluzione`, `Chiuso da`, `Gruppo di chiusura`,
     `ID interazione`, `Id Remedy`, `Descrizione`, `Soluzione`,
     `Servizio Interessato`, `Servizi Interessati`, `CI interessato`,
     `CI operativo`, `Ultimo aggiornamento da`)
```

Comment: the replace command works if the correct column is the primary key. Would it be worth editing your answer to ensure this is the case?

Comment: @Floris: It has nothing to do with which column is the primary key, but rather that a collision occurs with any `UNIQUE` key.